# What Does [Variable] = [OtherVariable] = [YetAnotherVariable] Mean?

Tags: c#

I am working in C# and have come across a statement similar to below:

```
var dog = anotherDog = someOtherDog;
```

What exactly is happening here? Is this just assigning the value of one variable to two others?

Comment: Why not just create a console application and test it?

Comment: Or a possibly better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737436

Comment: @DStanley that's a better duplicate, I think. The unfortunate piece behind the title is that one has to know that question relates, i.e. that "returning from assignment" is relevant. Thanks for the redirect, though; definitely learned something that I did not know previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

It is like

```
anotherDog = someOtherDog;
var dog = anotherDog;
```

You would have to have both anotherDog and someOtherDog to be declared already.